# Why do some commands not read from their standard input?

Tags: shell, pipe, arguments, stdin

I wonder what when we should use pipeline and when we shouldn't.

Say for instance, to kill certain process which handling pdf files, the following will not work by using pipeline:

```
ps aux | grep pdf | awk '{print $2}'|kill
```

Instead, we can only do it with following ways:

```
kill $(ps aux| grep pdf| awk '{print $2}')
```

or

```
ps aux | grep pdf | awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill
```

According to `man bash` ( version `4.1.2` ):

```
The standard output of command is connected via a pipe to the standard input of command2.
```

For above scenario:

- the stdin of `grep` is the stdout of `ps`. That works.
- the stdin of `awk` is the stdout of `grep`. That works.
- the stdin of `kill` is the stdout of `awk`. That doesn't work.

The stdin of the following command is always getting input from the previous command's stdout.

- Why doesn't it work with `kill` or `rm`?
- What's the different between `kill`, `rm` input with `grep`, `awk` input?
- Are there any rules?

Comment: This is not an answer but you might want to have a look at the `pgrep`, `pkill` and `killall` commands.

Comment: @terdon:I just use above scenario to show the pipeline issue, I understand that `pgrep` and the rest can achieve this perfectly :)

Answer (score 23):

This is an interesting question, and it deals with a part of the Unix/Linux philosophy.

So, what is the difference between programs like `grep`, `sed`, `sort` on  the one hand and `kill`, `rm`, `ls` on the other hand? I see two aspects.

#### The *filter* aspect

- The first kind of programs is also called **filters**. They take an input, either from a file or from STDIN, modify it, and generate some output, mostly to STDOUT. They are meant to be used in a pipe with other programs as sources and destinations.
- The second kind of programs acts on an input, but the output they give is often not related to the input. `kill` has no output when it works regularly, neither does `rm`. The just have a return value to show success. They do not normally take input from STDIN, but mostly give output to STDOUT.

For programs like `ls`, the filter aspect does not work that good. It can certainly have an input (but does not need one), and the output is closely related to that input, but it does not work as a filter. However, for that kind of programs, the other aspect still works:

#### The *semantic* aspect

- For filters, their input has **no semantic meaning**. They just read data, modify data, output data. It doesn't matter whether this is a list of numeric values, some filenames or HTML source code. The meaning of this data is only given by the code *you* provide to the filter: the regex for `grep`, the rules for `awk` or the Perl program.
- For other programs, like `kill` or `ls`, their input has a **meaning**, a **denotation**. `kill` expects process numbers, `ls` expects file or path names. They cannot handle arbitrary data and they are not meant to. Many of them do not even need any input or parameters, like `ps`. They do not normally read from STDIN.

One could probably combine these two aspects: A filter is a program whose input does not have a semantic meaning for the program.

I'm sure I have read about this philosophy somewhere, but I don't remember any sources at the moment, sorry. If someone has some sources present, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 18):

There are two common ways to provide inputs to programs:

- provide data to STDIN of the processes
- specify command line arguments

`kill` uses only command line arguments. It does not read from STDIN.
Programs like `grep` and `awk` read from STDIN (if no filenames are given as command line arguments) and process the data according to their command line arguments (pattern, statements, flags, ...).

You can only pipe to STDIN of other processes, not to command line arguments.

The common rule is, that programs uses STDIN to process arbitrary amount of data. All extra input parameters or, if there are usually only few at all, are passed by command line arguments. If the command line can get very long, for example for long `awk` program texts, there is often the possibility to read these from extra program files (`-f` option of `awk`).

To use the STDOUT of programs as command line arguments, use `$(...)` or in case of lots of data `xargs`. `find` can also this directly with `-exec ... {} +`.

For completeness: To write command line arguments to STDOUT, use `echo`.

Comment: How do we know a command will only take **arguments** but not STDIN ? Is there a systematic or programmatic way rather than guessing or read from man page ? By only reading the man page, I couldn't get any specific clues to be firm on whether the command can or cannot take STDIN, as STDIN is also part of the arguments from the way a man page present. For instance, `gzip`, in the SYNOPSIS, it didn't say it must take a FILENAME as input. I am looking is there a more systematic way to determine that.

Comment: There is also the "-" argument which means "stdin" (or "stdout") for some commands.

Comment: Won't `xargs` precisely allow you to "pipe to command line arguments"?

Comment: @T.Verron yes, this is the task of `xargs`. It calls the command if necessary more than once  (command line size is limited) and has lots of other options.

Comment: The text of the description will describe how you can use the program. For instance, gzip says: " The gzip program compresses and decompresses files using Lempel-Ziv coding (LZ77).  If no files are specified, gzip will compress from standard input, or decompress to standard output." If a man page does not mention standard input, it won't use it.

Comment: @sylye: *For instance, gzip, in the SYNOPSIS, it didn't say it must take a FILENAME as input* : It doesn't say it, because it doesn't need a FILENAME as input. gzip can compress file(s) in its argument list, and also can compress stdin (and output the compressed result on stdout). tar is the same. exemple: `ssh user@remote "tar cf - /some/dir | gzip -c -" >some_dir_from_remote.tar.gz`

Answer (score 6):

There are no "rules" as such. Some programs take input from STDIN, and some do not. If a program can take input from STDIN, it can be piped to, if not, it can't.

You can normally tell whether a program will take input or not by thinking about what it does. If the program's job is to somehow manipulate the *contents* of a file (e.g. `grep`, `sed`, `awk` etc.), it normally takes input from STDIN. If its job is to manipulate the file itself (e.g. `mv`,`rm`, `cp`) or a process (e.g. `kill`, `lsof`) or to return information about something (e.g. `top`, `find`, `ps`) then it doesn't.

Another way of thinking about it is the difference between arguments and input. For example:

```
mv foo bar
```

In the command above, `mv` has no input as such. What it has been given is two arguments. It does not know or care what is in either of the files, it just knows those are its arguments and it should manipulate them.

On the other hand

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/' < file
--- -- ------------   ----
 |   |       |          |-> input
 |   |       |------------> argument        
 |   |--------------------> option/flag/switch
 |------------------------> command
```

Here, `sed` has been given input as well as an argument. Since it takes input, it can read it from STDIN and it can be piped to.

It gets more complicated when an argument can *be* the input. For example

```
cat file
```

Here, `file` is the argument that was given to `cat`. To be precise, the file *name* `file` is the argument. However, since `cat` is a program that manipulates the contents of files, its input is whatever is inside `file`.

This can be illustrated using `strace`, a program that tracks the system calls made by processes. If we run `cat foo` via `strace`, we can see that the file `foo` is opened:

```
$ strace cat foo 2| grep foo
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "foo"], [/* 44 vars */]) = 0
open("foo", O_RDONLY)
```

The first line above shows that the program `/bin/cat` was called and its arguments were `cat` and `foo` (the first argument is always the program itself). Later on, the argument `foo` was opened in read only mode. Now, compare this with

```
$ strace ls foo 2| grep foo 
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "foo"], [/* 44 vars */]) = 0
stat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("foo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(1, "foo\n", 4foo
```

Here also, `ls` took itself and `foo` as arguments. However, there is no `open` call, the argument is not treated as input. Instead, `ls` calls the system's `stat` library (which is not the same thing as the `stat` command) to get information about the file `foo`.

In summary, if the command you're running will read its input, you can pipe to it, if it doesn't, you can't.

Comment: What is the meaning of 2 before pipe?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav that pipes stderr (standard error) instead of stdout

Answer (score 0):

- Why doesn't it work with kill or rm?

`kill` and `rm` do not need STDIN.

- What's the different between kill, rm input with grep, awk input?

For `kill` and `rm`, users provide their customized information as argument, and `$(cmd)` helps taking the STDOUT of `cmd` and converting it info argument.

For `grep` and `awk`, users provide arguments and in addition, also `STDIN` or a regular file that will be processed by the command.  `STDIN` can be passed with pipeline `|` or by manually inputting.

- Are there any rules?

Read the manual or the source codes.  And if you find nothing you need, you can make a simple but maybe dangerous test:

Just input the command you are curious about, with arguments that you have already understand, and see whether the command pause (nothing happen).  If it pause, it is actually waiting for STDIN (you can try `cat` and `echo` to see the different).  You manually type `Ctrl-D` and the command goes ahead (show results or errors) and returns.  Such a command needs STDIN in that situation (with arguments you provide).

The same command may not need STDIN in different situations (e.g., `cat` waits for STDIN but `cat file.txt` not).