# How can I pipe stdout to another program?

Tags: shell, pipe, git, stdout

I'm trying to setup a linter for my code and I only want to lint the coffeescript files that have changed in the current branch. So, I generate the list of files using `git`:

```
git diff --name-only develop | grep coffee$
```

That gives me a nice list of the files I'd like to process but I can't remember how to pipe this to the linting program to actually do the work. Basically I'd like something similar to `find`'s `-exec`:

```
find . -name \*.coffee -exec ./node_modules/.bin/coffeelint '{}' \;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're already piping to another program when you `git diff | grep`. Do you mean passing the previous command's output as arguments, [as with `xargs` or `$(...)`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140522/why-do-some-commands-not-read-from-their-standard-input/140524#140524)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` is the unix utility I was looking for. From the man page:

> ```
> The xargs utility reads space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited strings from the standard input and executes utility with the strings as arguments.
>
> Any arguments specified on the command line are given to utility upon each invocation, followed by some number of the arguments read from the standard input
>  of xargs.  The utility is repeatedly executed until standard input is exhausted.
> ```

So, the solution to my original question is:

```
git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only develop | grep coffee$ | xargs ./node_modules/.bin/coffeelint
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pipe through a while loop:

```
git diff --name-only develop | grep coffee$ | while IFS= read -r file; do
    ./node_modules/.bin/coffeelint "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just got this to work using `xargs`. `git diff --diff-filter=M --name-only develop | grep coffee$ | xargs ./node_modules/.bin/coffeelint`

Comment: @spinlock that will work as long as your file names don't contain newlines which is a safe enough assumption. It would be great if you could post that as an answer and [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: I don't have the karma to answer my own question yet. If I remember I'll come back in a day or two when I can.

Comment: @spinlock ah yes, new users need to wait a while. Well, thanks in advance if you do actually remember :)