# Why does the cd command handle STDIN different than other commands?

Tags: linux, shell, stdin

Commands like `cd` cannot have output piped to them in order to change directories--they require command-line arguments.

Why does the `cd` command (and those similar to it, such as `mv`, `cp`, & `rm`) not function like  most other commands when it comes to reading in `STDIN`? What's the logic behind preventing it from reading standard input to change directories?

The best [answer I could find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50022/why-cant-i-redirect-a-path-name-output-from-one-command-to-cd?rq=1) stated:

> cd is not an external command - it is a shell builtin function. It runs in the context of the current shell, and not, as external commands do, in a fork/exec'd context as a separate process.

However, to me the above answer does not really explain it at all: Why does `cd` handle `STDIN` different than many other commands who read in `STDIN`?

Comment: `echo 'hi' | cd /` produces no errors here with Bash on Linux (though nor does it change the current working directory, as I'm sure is explained somewhere else on the site). Which shell are you using that's giving an error? Or is this a question about what's allowed per POSIX standards?

Comment: In answer to the question posed in the title, `cd` doesn't always require an argument to change directories. Example: `cd / ; pwd` and now `cd ; pwd`. No argument supplied but the directory changed.

Comment: I was wondering more of what the advantages are of having cd not function like other commands when it comes to reading in `STDIN`--I don't understand why it's different

Comment: `cd` isn't alone in ignoring _stdin_. Here's another example, `echo hello | sleep 60`

Comment: Because, as mentioned, a pipeline might want to take `stdout` and dump it into `stdin` to a tool that is executed from another working directory.  `cd` doesn't read or write anything; it merely changes the working directory and therefore never taps into the pipeline at all.  Asking why `cd` doesn't tap in to the pipeline is like asking why `echo` doesn't read the partition table.

Comment: Related: [Why do some commands not read from their standard input?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140522/why-do-some-commands-not-read-from-their-standard-input)

Comment: There are many commands like `cd`: `mv`, `cp`, `rm` are three examples. I'd say that `cd` is consistent by not reading from stdin.

Comment: One the one hand: a bunch of commands that reading stdin. On the other hand, a bunch of commands that don't read stdin. How can you single out one command from the second bunch?

Comment: What do you mean by “different than other commands”? It's extremely rare for a command to accept the same things on standard input and on the command line. What on earth made you think that this was a common thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commands that read `stdin` are almost all of the filter family, i.e. programs that transform a flow of text data to a transformed one.

`cat` , `sed`, `awk`, `gzip` and even `sh` are good examples of such "filters".

The cited commands, `cp`, `mv` and `rm` are definitely not filters but commands that do things with the arguments passed, here files or directories.

The `cd` command is similar to them, it expects an argument (or simulate a default one if not provided), and generally doesn't output anything on `stdout`, although it might output something on it in some cases like when using `CDPATH`.

Even if one want to create a `cd` variant that take the target directory from stdin, it wouldn't have any effect when used in a pipeline in the Bourne shell, `dash` and `bash` to name a few. The last component of the command being run in a subshell, the change to a new directory won't affect the current shell. e.g.: `echo /tmp | cd` would work with `ksh93` but not `bash`, `dash`, `zsh`, `sh`, ...

`cd <(echo /tmp)` would work with shells supporting process substitution (at least `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`) but wouldn't have any significant advantage compared to `cd $(echo tmp)`

The only use case that might be of interest would be something like:

```
echo tmp | (cd ; pwd)
```

Finally, such a variant would need to sort out the case it was given no argument but the expected behavior is to change the directory to the users's home or it was given no argument but the expected behavior is to read the name of the target directory from stdin. As there is no reliable way to decide, this is doomed.

Comment: But if, like you said, `cd` outputs on stdout on some cases, isn't the logical next step to make `cd` also accept input? I'm just trying to understand the design logic behind it.

Comment: My bad, `cd` output to stderr, not stdout. In any case, as I already wrote in my last paragraph, implementing such a feature would be pointless as not compatible with POSIX conforming shells, i.e. `cd` won't be able to change the current directory, quite a limitation given the fact this command has no other purpose.

Comment: @Roflicide no, a large number of commands write to stdout. Asking them all to accept stdin is not necessarily logical.

Answer (score 3):

Command-line arguments are not at all the same thing as stdin; even commands that use both generally use them for different things. Take `cat` for example:

```
echo foo bar | cat    # outputs "foo bar"
cat foo bar           # looks for files named "foo" and "bar", and concatenates them (if found)
```

If you look at most other commands that read from stdin, you'll find similar things: they don't treat arguments and stdin interchangeably, but as ways of providing different kinds of information to the command.

There are some commands that can take the same type of info either way, but even in those cases there's usually an option you have to specify to tell it which to use. For example, `perl` reads its program from stdin unless it's told to do otherwise:

```
echo 'print 1' | perl    # runs "print 1" as a perl program, which prints "1"
perl -e 'print 1'        # runs "print 1" as a perl program, which prints "1"
perl print 1             # tries to run a file named "print" as a script, giving it the argument "1"
```

...So, I think the premise of the question is false: most commands do not take the same sort of info from stdin that they do from the arguments, so `cd` is not unusual in this respect.