# Pipe vs Command substitution

Tags: pipe, echo, command-substitution, touch

Testing with the linux command line and pipe I tried to do `echo {1..3} | touch` and it doesn't work. I achieved the results with `touch $(echo {1..3})`.

Why I can't pass the list generated by echo to touch using the pipe as in the first example?

Comment: Related: [Why do some commands not read from their standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140522/why-do-some-commands-not-read-from-their-standard-input)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to steeldriver for his comment, it guided me to the answer.

The pipe operator only works when the command accepts arguments from stdin, in this case commands like touch or rm does not, an alternative solution is to use command sustitution as in the example

```
touch $(echo {1..3})
```

Or by using the xargs which converts input from standard input into arguments to a command, hence is possible to do

```
echo {1..3} | xargs touch
```

as simple as that